# systemd-journald[304]: Journal stopped

Tags: shutdown, systemd, systemd-journald

Whenever I try to shutdown my system, it just ends up stuck on a black screen with a blinking cursor in the top left.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I have done a fresh install of Ubuntu twice with no effect.

In the terminal 'journalctl -rb -1' shows that last night after shutdown it ended on

```
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd-journald[304]: Journal stopped
```

and then stayed on the black screen with top left flashing cursor until the morning when I forced it to shutdown by holding the power button which was at 0900. So it looks like shutdown was complete? If not why did the journal stop last night and not this morning?

Here's the full log from 'journal -rb -1':

```
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd-journald[304]: Journal stopped
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: Shutting down.
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: Reached target Power-Off.
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: Finished Power-Off.
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: systemd-poweroff.service: Succeeded.
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: Reached target Final Step.
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: Reached target Shutdown.
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: Stopped Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: systemd-remount-fs.service: Succeeded.
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: Stopped Create System Users.
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: systemd-sysusers.service: Succeeded.
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: Stopped Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service: Succeeded.
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: Stopped target Local File Systems (Pre).
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: Removed slice system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: Stopped File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/AC08-C846.
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-AC08\x2dC846.service: Succeeded.
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: Reached target Unmount All Filesystems.
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: Unmounted /boot/efi.
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: boot-efi.mount: Succeeded.
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for code, revision 85.
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: snap-code-85.mount: Succeeded.
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for snapd, revision 11036.
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: snap-snapd-11036.mount: Succeeded.
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for snap-store, revision 518.
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: snap-snap\x2dstore-518.mount: Succeeded.
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for gtk-common-themes, revision 1514.
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1514.mount: Succeeded.
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for gnome-3-34-1804, revision 66.
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-66.mount: Succeeded.
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for core18, revision 1988.
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: snap-core18-1988.mount: Succeeded.
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for core, revision 12603.
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: snap-core-12603.mount: Succeeded.
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for canonical-livepatch, revision 126.
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-126.mount: Succeeded.
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: Stopped target Swap.
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: Unmounted /run/snapd/ns.
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: run-snapd-ns.mount: Succeeded.
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: Unmounting /run/snapd/ns...
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: Unmounted /run/snapd/ns/canonical-livepatch.mnt.
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: run-snapd-ns-canonical\x2dlivepatch.mnt.mount: Succeeded.
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: Unmounting Mount unit for snapd, revision 11036...
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: Unmounting Mount unit for snap-store, revision 518...
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: Unmounting Mount unit for gtk-common-themes, revision 1514...
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: Unmounting Mount unit for gnome-3-34-1804, revision 66...
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: Unmounting Mount unit for core18, revision 1988...
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: Unmounting Mount unit for core, revision 12603...
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: Unmounting Mount unit for code, revision 85...
Jan 27 22:18:01 moz systemd[1]: Unmounting Mount unit for canonical-livepatch, revision 126...
```